# Calling Class Attributes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a Python Programming text where it's creating a scene within a game with the following code:

```py
class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
        "You died.  You kinda suck at this.",
        "Your Mom would be proud...if she were smarter.",
        "Such a luser.",
        "I have a small puppy that's better at this.",
        "You're worse than your Dad's jokes."

    ]

    def enter(self):
        print(Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)])
```

My question is just over the last line. What's the difference when using a specific class name, in this case `Death.quips` as opposed to `self.quips`. The latter is how I've always seen it but it's used differently here. My first thought was maybe it bypasses needing to first create an object, but in this example `self.quips` requires the object anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, they are accomplishing the same thing in the scenario. `Death.quips` is calling to the quips attribute of the class. Using self.quips is referring to the specific object of the class. You can change attributes on objects as well.

For example, if you changed `Death.quips` to `self.quips` you could do the following:

```
>>> a = Death()
>>> a.enter()
Such a luser.
>>> a.quips = [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e"

    ]
>>> a.enter()
c
>>>
```

But, if you were to keep it Death.quips, this would be the result:

```
>>> a = Death()
>>> a.enter()
You died.  You kinda suck at this.
>>> a.quips = [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e"

    ]
>>> a.enter()
Such a luser.
>>>
```

`Self` refers to the attributes of the instantiated object, while `Death` is referring to the unchanged attribute of the overall class.

I hope this helps and makes sense

Answer (score 1):

in this you can directly access the quips list as `x = Death.quips` without intialise it.

if you used `self` then you need to intialise the class first (using `def __init__()`) and in that you need to define `quips`. then you could access it as

```
x = Death()
quips_ = x.quips
```

else to directly access it, you needed to add the `@staticmethod` before a class method which provide u the list